# weird Error JS cannot access 'r' before initialization

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, three.js

I used THREE.js's raycaster to bind a mouse event with my 3D model. It can run in my
dev environment. but after I built it(I used VUE.js)  and runned it in pro environment, **Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'r' before initialization** occured.

original codes in that FUNC:

```
raycast( raycaster, intersects ) {

        const geometry = this.geometry;
        const material = this.material;
        const matrixWorld = this.matrixWorld;
                
                ...

                const start = Math.max( 0, drawRange.start );
        const end = Math.min( index.count, ( drawRange.start + drawRange.count ) );
                
        for ( let i = start, il = end; i < il; i += 3 ) {}
}
```

builded codes in that FUNC:

```
raycast(t, e) {
              const n = this.geometry
              , i = this.material
              , r = this.matrixWorld;
                
              ...
             
              // ERROR HERE
              // Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'r' before initialization
              for (let n = Math.max(0, r.start), r = Math.min(s.count, r.start + r.count); n < r; n += 3){}
}
```

I written some codes like the ERROR codes, And the exactlly ERROR occured:

```
      const a = {age: 10}
      for (let b = a.age, a = 11; b < a; b++ ) {
        console.log(a)
      }
```

MY CODE :

```
  mounted() {
    this.init3D();
    this.animate();
  },
  methods: {
    init3D() {

      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1500);
      this.camera.position.set(0.283, 8.3658, 6.1424);
      this.camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

      let ambLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
      this.scene.add(ambLight);

      let dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
      dirLight.position.set(400, 600, 400);
      this.scene.add(dirLight);

      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});//alpha: true,
      this.renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
      this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      this.renderer.setSize(this.scaleWidth, this.scaleHeight);
      document.querySelector('#container3D').appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

      this.labelRenderer = new CSS2DRenderer();
      this.labelRenderer.setSize(this.scaleWidth, this.scaleHeight);
      this.labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
      this.labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0px';
      document.querySelector('#container3D').appendChild(this.labelRenderer.domElement);

      this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.labelRenderer.domElement);
      this.controls.mouseButtons = {LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN, MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY, RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE};
      this.controls.minDistance = 0.01;
      this.controls.target.set(0.2268, -0.406, 0.153);
      this.controls.update();
      this.controls.maxPolarAngle = 1.5;
      this.controls.minDistance = 2.5;
      this.controls.maxDistance = 17;

      this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0), 0, 20000);

      this.addSky();
      this.loadModel();
      this.loadPyramid();
      this.loadColumn();
      this.initLight();

      this.waveGroup = new THREE.Group();
      this.scene.add(this.waveGroup);
      this.areaTxtGroup = new THREE.Group();
      this.scene.add(this.areaTxtGroup);
      this.portraitGroup = new THREE.Group();
      this.scene.add(this.portraitGroup);
      this.pyramidGroup = new THREE.Group();
      this.scene.add(this.pyramidGroup);
      this.columnGroup = new THREE.Group();
      this.scene.add(this.columnGroup);

      this.wavePointTex = this.texLoader.load(this.wavePointImg);
      this.waveTex = this.texLoader.load(this.waveImg);
      this.circularTex = this.texLoader.load(this.circularImg);
      document.querySelector('#container3D').addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
      document.querySelector('#container3D').addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    },
    onMouseMove(event) {

      let _this = this;

      let pointer = new THREE.Vector2((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);
      this.raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, this.camera);
      // ERROR HERE
      let intersections = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(_this.scene.children, true);
      ...
    }
}
```

what should I do to fix it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ2za.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caLTz.png)

EXTRA:

I build with command `npm buildPro`
HERE ARE MY package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve --port *** --open",
    "pro": "vue-cli-service serve --open --mode production",
    "buildDev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "buildPro": "vue-cli-service build --mode production",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=2048 increase-memory-limit"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^18.6.4",
    "ailabel": "^4.1.3",
    "animated-number-vue": "^1.0.0",
    "async-validate": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "backbone": "1.3.3",
    "brace": "^0.11.1",
    "button-dropdown": "^1.0.10",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.0",
    "codemirror": "^5.49.0",
    "collision": "^0.1.0",
    "countup": "^1.8.2",
    "cropperjs": "^1.2.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.0",
    "iview": "^3.2.2",
    "iview-area": "^1.5.17",
    "jointjs": "2.1.4",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "js-base64": "^2.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.0",
    "lodash": "3.10.1",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "save-svg-as-png": "^1.4.17",
    "simplemde": "^1.11.2",
    "sortablejs": "^1.7.0",
    "spark-md5": "^3.0.2",
    "sql-formatter": "^2.3.3",
    "three": "^0.143.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.3.0",
    "v-scale-screen": "^1.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.10",
    "vue-animate-number": "^0.4.2",
    "vue-clipboard2": "^0.3.1",
    "vue-codemirror": "^4.0.6",
    "vue-contextmenujs": "^1.3.12",
    "vue-cron": "^1.0.9",
    "vue-easy-printer": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-grid-layout": "^2.3.7",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.8.0",
    "vue-json-editor": "^1.4.3",
    "vue-json-excel": "^0.3.0",
    "vue-json-viewer": "^2.2.11",
    "vue-menu-button": "^0.2.3",
    "vue-query-builder": "^0.8.2",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-to-pdf": "^1.0.0",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",

  },
```

sorry for my poor English

Comment: in the for loop, you effectively have `let r = Math.min(s.count, r.start + r.count)` ... the "outer" `r` is NOT accessible, so it's trying to use the `r` you just declared ... use a different variable name in the for loop

Comment: THANK YOU, i know that , but how  i change the code after  built and runned in pro envirentment

Comment: fix code, rebuild, re-deploy

Comment: I tried. that func is in THREE.js dependency. I copied it to my Project, and I changed  that variable name, but after I rebuild, that variable name still change to 'r'.

Comment: Something is wrong with code uglify, three different variables uglified to same variable name in the same scope? `const matrixWorld = this.matrixWorld;` to `r = this.matrixWorld`, `drawRange.start` to `r.start` and `il = end` to `r = Math.min...`, How this can be possible? am i missing something?

Comment: oh, that's not your code? that's not good! whatever is uglifying that code is doing a poor job!!

Comment: it confued me too.    )  :

Comment: It would be easy to understand if you can provide more details like what exactly you copied or how you've integrated three.js into your project? what are your build configurations? etc

Comment: How are you building/minifying your project? You say "build with vue" - does that mean you're running `npm build` and/or `vite build`? What's in your `package.json` for build? This could be a bug in `vite build` which looks like they use https://github.com/evanw/esbuild. This could be a bug in esbuild, if this is what you're using then you should file a bug with them. It could also be a bug in terser but again this depends on how you're building your project. This is also surprising because minification errors like this shouldn't exist in 2023. Maybe Vite/Vue are not high quality?

Comment: I use `npm buid`,  I copied entire file 'three.module.js' and import it. I am trying to change my `code uglify dependency`.  THANK YOU  ALL, I  HOPE IT WORK .

Comment: still not working. putted my `package.json` on my qustion description

Comment: You didn't read my comment. Also, `vue-cli-service`/Vue CLI [is deprecated](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html). Read the warning at the top of the page. ` Vue CLI also has a bug, you're seeing a bug in Vue. File a bug with https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli. Also make sure your dependencies like vue-cli are up to date and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a scope issue.

First i'll explain using the simple example you gave:

```
const a = {age: 10}
for (let b = a.age, a = 11; b < a; b++ ) {
  console.log(a)
}
```

Inside the for loop, you create a variable `"b"` and try to set it to `"a"` (referring to the outside `"a = {age: 10}"`, then you create a new variable with same name (`"a = 11"`).

However, due to JavaScript's Temporal Dead Zone (TDZ), TDZ automatically declare the for loop variables before the loop itself, shadowing all other variables with same name outside, so you get the error `"ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization"`

This means that all variables inside your loop is automatically declared, but not inicialized, by TDZ. So, when you tried to set `"b"` to `"a.age"`, the `"a"` is already declared by TDZ, shadowing the outside `"a = {age: 10}"` and then, javascript tries to set `"b"` to this new `"a"` thats is only declaration and dont have any value because it is not inicialized iet.

===

So, when I read the code in the second image you uploaded, I identified the same issue:
[image]

...

[image]

the `"r.start"` is not reffering to your outsite `"r = this.matrixWorld"` but reffer to the `"r = math.min()"` declared inside the for loop

Comment: Thanks for ur explicit explaination.   My question is that the error code is NOT MY CODE.  It's generated from  dependency  after I build my project.